# Keep getting ERROR: with function tabledap

Tags: r

I keep getting a returned "Error:" with my code but have no idea why when the same code works fine with a similar dataset.

Changed the observation variable, changed the time restrictions, searched for similar problems online

```
library(rerddap)

CalPoly = info("HABs-CalPoly", url= "http://erddap.sccoos.org/erddap/")

CalPoly_Data = tabledap(CalPoly, 
                    fields = c('Ceratium','Cochlodinium', 'Dinophysis_spp', 'Gymnodinium_spp','time'),
                    'time>=2008-08-15T00:00:00Z', 'time<=2019-05-26T05:35:00Z')
```

Should return a data table but I just keep getting "Error:"

This similar code does work though and I have no idea why

```
CalCOFI = info('siocalcofiHydroCasts')
calcofi.df <- tabledap(CalCOFI, 
                   fields = c('cst_cnt',  'date', 'year', 'month', 'julian_date', 'julian_day', 'rpt_line', 'rpt_sta', 'cruz_num', 'intchl', 'intc14', 'time'),
                   'time>=1984-01-01T00:00:00Z', 'time<=2014-04-17T05:35:00Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue!

I initially set the url correctly for the info argument, I didn't realize I had to set the url again for the tabledap argument. I did not realized it the Default is: https://upwell.pfeg.noaa.gov/ erddap/

Five hours later but at least it is resolved!

The code now works:

```
     CalPoly_Data = tabledap(CalPoly, fields = c('Temp','time'),'time>=2008-08-15T07:00:00Z', 'time<=2019-05-26T07:00:00Z', url = "http://erddap.sccoos.org/erddap/")
```